# Mails not getting sent by php

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have a simple script that works fine on any of my other servers, but on that one I need, it doesn't...

```
    <?php
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];

$formcontent="Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone No: $phone \n Services: $services \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "gaurav.m@momentsworld.com";
$subject = "Client Details";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='../contact.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'>Return Home</a>";
?>
```

When I try to submit contact details through form, it gives an error

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\momentsworld.com\httpdocs\script\quick_query.php on line 17
```

Although the same script works fine on other servers... Plz Help

Comment: you are running it on local server?

Comment: You need an MTA installed on your server like PostFix, qmail or sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
ini_set("SMTP","localhost");
ini_set("smtp_port",25);
ini_set("sendmail_from","sender_mail@gmail.com");

$too = "receiver_mail@yahoo.com" ;
$subject = "TEST" ;
$message = "User message" ;
$user_email = "user_mail@gmail.com" ;

$headers = "From: $user_email " ;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $too " ;
$headers .= "Return-Path: $too " ;
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion (). " " ;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . " " ;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; UTF-8' . " " ;

if( mail ( $too , $subject , $message , $headers )) echo 'SENT' ;

?>
```

Even if its not working in your server, you can try sendmail or Swiftmailer. Check the below link:

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html

Answer (score 0):

Your server mail sending settings are not configured.check the server mail sending settings and enable all email sending settings of server.Another way is send mail using smtp.Sample code will look like:

1. Your config array settings.

   ```
   $config = Array(
     'protocol' => 'smtp',
     'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
     'smtp_port' => 465,
     'smtp_timeout'=>'30',
     'smtp_user' => 'your_gmail_account@gmail.com',
     'smtp_pass' => 'your gmail password',
     'mailtype'  => 'html',
     'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
     '_smtp_auth' => TRUE,
     'newline' => "\r\n"
   );
   ```
2. Initialize that config settings and then use mail sending code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems sendmail is not configured in this server. Please ask IT guys to install & configure it for you. Unless mail server is not running you would not be able to send email. In addition, using gmail or other as SMTP provider will work for testing purpose. With high volume of emails, I guess they would blacklist your IP.

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same problem. So i switched over to PHPMailer library. You can user that. That will be helpful even sending images. You can find the PHPMailer document and example code here.

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examples

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Linux server, we have installed mailx before, which then allowed the PHP mail() tag to be used.

Also, PHPMailer (as mentioned above) is another great suggestion, utilizing SMTP to remote servers.